# Spring Batch and JiBX: how to debug?

Tags: spring-batch, jibx

I am testing Spring Batch 2.1.9 on Spring ToolSuite 3.1.0.RELEASE Build Id: 201210061306.
All the depend jars are contained inside the project thro' Gradle/Maven.

I compiled my schema using JiBX on JDK1.6 and run the Spring Batch test program on JDK1.7.

But I got issue with JiBX (1.2.4.5):

The schema jar for my source schema should be correct (i.e. contains the JiBX_binding*" classes) as the job using this jibx-marshaller did complete but only the readcount is zero.

Any hint and recommendation is welcome.

Thanks